# SQL как правильно посчитать суммы, если N равен m

Tags: sql, sql-server

Пытаюсь посчитать сумму из базы данных в таком порядке:

Если `[KW] = '99'`, то `'KW 99: ' + cast(SUM(N_KH) as varchar)`

если `[KW]` < (меньше) `'97'` то `'Summe Laufend: ' + cast(SUM(N_KH) as varchar)`

если `[KW]` <= (между)`'1'` и `'99'` то `'Summe Total: ' + cast(SUM(N_KH) as varchar)`

---

пытался посчитать вот таким способом

```
Select case 
         when KW = '99' 
            then 'KW 99: ' + cast(SUM(N_KH) as varchar) 
         when KW < '97'
            then 'Summe Laufend: ' + cast(SUM(N_KH) as varchar) 
        when KW >= '99'
            then 'Summe Total: ' + cast(SUM(N_KH) as varchar) 
        end as Woche
FROM [ATX_PLSNG].[dbo].[Terminliste]
Group by KW
```

Получаю в итоге таблицу из нескольких `Summe Laufend, NULL, KW` и тд
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить суммы как на скриншоте ниже, то есть в три записи и все
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: обычно люди такие выборки в столбцы делают, а не строки. Чем вас не устраивает вариант с одной строкой и тремя столбцами?

Comment: @teran незнанием. Не понимаю как сделать хоть в строки, хоть в столбцы

Comment: а в условиях у вас точно нужно что первое `=` 99, а последнее `>= 99`, то есть включает первое? и 98 пропускается?

Comment: @teran первое, включает только 99, второе все, до 97 и последние все включая 99
https://i.imgur.com/nXnAvB9.png вот так выглядит, если в столбик.. если я правильно все сделал.. теперь бы все посчитать их вместе, чтобы все было в 1 строку и в 3 стобца или наоброт, 1 столбец и 3 строки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По столбцам:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN KW = 99 THEN N_KH ELSE 0 END) AS [KW 99]
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN KW < 97 THEN N_KH ELSE 0 END) AS [Summe Laufend]
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN KW BETWEEN 1 AND 99 THEN N_KH ELSE 0 END) AS [Summe Total]
  FROM [ATX_PLSNG].[dbo].[Terminliste]
```

По строкам:

```
SELECT [unpvt].[KW_Type] + ': ' + CAST([S] AS varchar(20))
  FROM (
           SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN KW = 99 THEN N_KH ELSE 0 END) AS [KW 99]
                 ,SUM(CASE WHEN KW < 97 THEN N_KH ELSE 0 END) AS [Summe Laufend]
                 ,SUM(CASE WHEN KW BETWEEN 1 AND 99 THEN N_KH ELSE 0 END) AS [Summe Total]
             FROM [ATX_PLSNG].[dbo].[Terminliste]
       ) AS [p]
       UNPIVOT
       (
           [S] FOR [KW_Type] IN ([KW 99], [Summe Laufend], [Summe Total])
       ) AS [unpvt];
```

Подробнее про UNPIVOT можно почитать в документации: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: там не `between` а `>=99`

Comment: когда пытаюсь из этого сделать в View - получаю ошибку из за `=` `<` и `between`

Comment: @Insider В вопросе нет НИЧЕГО про view? Вот нафига задавать один вопрос, желая получить ответ на совсем другой?

Comment: @Insider замените все iif на `сase`

Comment: @teran при замене, показывает ошибки на = < и between

Comment: Значит как-то не так поменяли. Я переписал ответ с CASE. Версия SQL Server как я понимаю меньше чем 2012, да? Если используете старые версии, то лучше об этом сразу предупреждать в тексте вопроса.

Comment: @sybexgod на самом деле установлена 2016. почему не работает, хороший вопрос

Comment: И мой вариант у вас тоже не работает? Тогда хотелось бы узнать, какие типы у столбцов KW и N_KH.

Comment: @sybexgod нет, который вы изменили, работает. KW и N_KH, оба INT. А что нужно изменить, чтобы в 3 строки а не столца?

Comment: Добавил вариант со строками. Хотя обычно такие развороты стараются делать средствами клиентского приложения.